# My Dropdown Navigation is pushing my main navigation aside when it drops

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

[image]

I am trying to make a central drop down so that it fits nicely on a screen. But my "position: relative;" is causing havoc to my navigation when the mouse hovers over, and spreading them out as show on the image.

I appreciate any help or advice

```
.structure-mainnavigation ul li ul {
  width:850px;
  position: relative;
}

.structure-mainnavigation ul li ul li {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  left: auto;
  right: 4px; 
}
```

Comment: Give it `position:absolute`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i've tried that, and although it fixes the navigation problem, my drop down goes to the right, and off the screen

Comment: Perhaps you should add more context to your question so we understand what is the desired behavior. I do believe your final purpose is not to add `position:relative` to a particular page element, but to open a menu or whatnot. Please create a working [mcve] in the question itself, linking the required resources, so we could understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could position it absolutely. Try:

```
.structure-mainnavigation ul li ul {
  width:850px;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.structure-mainnavigation ul li {
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: This pushed all of my navigation to the left side of the page

Comment: Of course, you will have to figure out how to reposition the elements... Why don't you post the whole code in code editor so we have something to work on..

Comment: I've sussed it with what you gave. Thanks Varin